# File Path in windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a alphabet.xaml in root . and i call this code for reading xml file :

```
 _loadedData = XDocument.Load("Assets/xml/alphabet.xml").Descendants("item");
```

every thing works good .

now i create a folder "AppService" in the root and in that folder i create a class file "service.cs" .

now i move the code above in service.cs class as a seprated method "XmlDocumentLoader()" . and i use it in Alphabet.xaml like this :

```
AppService appService = new AppService();
var a = appService.XmlDocumentLoader("Assets/xml/alphabet.xml", "item");
```

but now i get error . there is something wrong with address . but i dont know what should i do .

can you guide me what change i have to apply on my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the folder path context up one level (to make the root as current context) by using `../` at the beginning, then you can continue using the path you already have :

```
var a = appService.XmlDocumentLoader("../Assets/xml/alphabet.xml", "item");
```